# Why don't all cells have active telomerase?

Tags: telomere

If telomere degeneration plays a role in aging, and extending them is biologically possible with telomerase, why isn't it active in all cells? Humans use it in their germ cells, so why not all somatic cells too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't want all body cells dividing indefinitely. When that happens we call it "cancer".

Telomeres are one of many ways to regulate cell division and prevent runaway growth in a last-ditch manner where a cell becomes non-viable after dividing too many times without telomeres. From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomerase):

> With telomerase activation some types of cells and their offspring become immortal (bypass the Hayflick limit), thus avoiding cell death as long as the conditions for their duplication are met. Many cancer cells are considered 'immortal' because telomerase activity allows them to live much longer than any other somatic cell, which, combined with uncontrollable cell proliferation[46] is why they can form tumors. A good example of immortal cancer cells is HeLa cells, which have been used in laboratories as a model cell line since 1951.

and:

> Telomerase activation has been observed in ~90% of all human tumors,[48] suggesting that the immortality conferred by telomerase plays a key role in cancer development. Of the tumors without TERT activation,[49] most employ a separate pathway to maintain telomere length termed Alternative Lengthening of Telomeres (ALT).[50] The exact mechanism behind telomere maintenance in the ALT pathway is unclear, but likely involves multiple recombination events at the telomere.